# php server deploy => just download the file

Tags: php, firebase

I want to run this PHP code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount('hghj-f803a9.json')
->withDatabaseUri('https://hahgj-f803a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');
$database = $factory->createDatabase();

 if (!empty($_GET["username"]) && !empty($_GET["password"])) {
    if ($_GET["username"] == "per" && $_GET["password"] == "mobile") {
        echo "welcome";
   } else {
        echo "wrong username or password";
    }
} else {
    echo "username and password are empty";
}
```

in a host server I tried with firebase, but when I access the url/index.php(which includes that code) it just downloads the file.

but when I run it in my xampp server it runs

[image] [image] [image]

I tried to deploy it in firebase but it just downloads the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase hosting is a host for static websites

Firebase hosting does not support any server side scripts such as Ruby, PHP, Python or anything else that is processing your files before output. That would require a application engine such as Google App Engine, Heroku, or similar. The hosting service is a static website hosting service. But you know what is not server side script? JavaScript!

[reference](https://medium.com/evenbit/gateway-to-firebase-hosting-dda81e83fcfa#:%7E:text=Firebase%20hosting%20does%20not%20support,a%20static%20website%20hosting%20service.)